# Variable for '%' in multiple files matching

Tags: makefile

I would like to make a complete text document from several sources (since one of the file source change, I want the doc to change).

I have to pass it through a translator I develop.  I would like to pass the language as argument, to make it cleaner.

Yesterday, late at night, I dreamed of a makefile like this...

```
#makefile
# ...
my_complete_doc.%.html: my_trans_exe header.%.html $(wildcard source/*.%.html)
        $< --language $(variable_for_%) > $@
```

(?) Does it replace `%` by all the languages which have their own `header.language.html` files.  And does the file `my_completed_doc.language.html` get changed as soon as one of the `source/*.language.html` get changed?

(?) How to get the `%` replaced in several prerequisites, possibly into the wildcard and necessarily in the recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the easy problem: you wish to use the '%' variable in the recipe. The answer is to use the '$*' automatic variable:

```
my_complete_doc.%.html: my_trans_exe ...
    $< --language $* > $@
```

Then the easy question: yes, the `header.%.html` prerequisite is correct. When you try to build `my_complete_doc.dutch.html` then Make will evaluate it as `header.dutch.html`, when you try to build `my_complete_doc.french.html`, Make will evaluate it as `header.french.html`.

Now the tricky problem: the prerequisite `$(wildcard source/*.%.html)`. Ordinarily, Make expands `$(wildcard ...)` statements *before executing any rule, or deciding which targets to build.* So it searches for any files such as `source/foo.%.html` or `source/bar.%.html` (that is, files whose names contain the character '%'), finds none, and evaluates the statement as an empty string. But Make will defer this evaluation until it has chosen the rule, if you use `SECONDEXPANSION`:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
my_complete_doc.%.html: my_trans_exe header.%.html $$(wildcard source/*.%.html)
    $< --language $* > $@
```

(Note the '$$'. In the first -- ordinary -- expansion, Make reduces "$$(...)" to "$(...)", and in the second -- when '%' has a value -- it expands "$(...)".) Now if you modify any file such as `source/foo.german.html`, Make will consider the file `my_complete_doc.german.html` out of date and in need of rebuilding.